# PHP batch with progress bar

Tags: php, excel, batch-file, import, progress-bar

I've been searching about PHP batch tutorials, but nothing so far.

I've been given a task to import data from MS Excel. For each excel data, will be processed by PHP to create mysql rows.

Because of complexity of 1 excel data, I want to build a batch system, where PHP process 1 row at a time, display some progress bar. Then prevent timeout (which is set to 60 seconds).

Any guidelines / example / etc for this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you actually talking about an MS Excel file (BIFF .xls or OfficeOPenXML .xlsx) file, or a CSV file?

Comment: sorry for long reply, the file is .excel. but perhaps csv is fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for prevent timeout you must put **set_time_limit(0);** at first of code if you want browser didn't timeout you must echo some data and flush for browser

Comment: sorry for long reply, any technical details?

Comment: you can call script by cron job with this work. you can process excel data completely.if you have more than one excel file you must list them on DB and process one of them per request and signed as completed that next request process another excel file.see this maybe help you http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-batch/

Answer (score 0):

Usually for CSVs I would use `fgetcsv` - http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php - which will let you do one line at a time.

For the progress bar you could update a [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp) file for every row processed and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) request from the browser to read that file and display the progress bar for the client on the frontend with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but I'll give it a shot. from my understanding you want a batch file to stimulate a progress bar while your PHP program thingy is running.

Well, first you'd need to know how many cells you need to do whatever it is that you want to do with. So long as this is possible (and it can export the number to a text file) then it should be possible.

The following method will need a .txt file when it runs to contain the amount of cells you need to process (you should probably skip this whole answer if you can't). It will then scan for a different text file that contains the amount of cells already processed (preferably that's the only thing in the file, otherwise this could turn hairy).

Knowing me and my talk before thinking lifestyle, this answer will probably never get submitted because I'm an idiot and over estimated what I could accomplish.

So, without further ado...

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in (file1) do set num1=%%i
set /a num1*=100
:update
if not exist file2 goto update
for /f %%i in (file2) do (
    if %%i equ %prog% goto update
    set prog=%%i
)
set /a prog*=100
set /a stat=%prog%/%num1%
cls
echo %stat% % done.
goto update
```

Well, that worked out better than I expected. This answer might just get published. One thing I should note is that you need to replace `file1` and `file2` (which has two occurrences) with the file path of the appropriate file. file1 should contain the amount of cells that you need to do whatever that stuff up there was. file2 should have an updated amount of cells that you have processed.

Unfortunately I didn't test this and I'm sure that there will be an error or some sort of improvement that can be made. It was made to be a template and inspire some other idea, not to be a hard copy.

Comment: I didn't think it was worth an edit, so I thought I should mention that when I say cells or boxes, I mean rows.